# Is there a way to remove border of swt button or at least to make bounds of border equal to that of button only on windows

Tags: java, windows, button, swt, noborder

I have created an swt button but I can see there is a white border around the button. Is there anyway I can make the border bounds equal to button or remove that white border around the button?
This issue I'm facing only on windows. On MacOs I don't see any white border around these buttons.

I did try using SWT.FLAT while creating the button and I also tried using GridData to set the widthHint, HeightHint to 0 but nothing helped.

Comment: Maybe try  calling`setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT)` on the parent `Composite`, also try `SWT.INHERIT_FORCE`

Comment: Yes, SWT.INHERIT_FORCE worked for me.
Thank you!!